# Facebook Android SDK randomly stopped working

Tags: java, android, facebook, sdk

I have integrated Facebook into my Android app and was able to post to my profile wall. After a few days, I go to do it again and I get "An Error has occurred with MyApp. Please try again later."

Does anyone know why this is happening? It was working fine before.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check your authToken for expiration? You could ask for the "offline_access" for it never to expire. 
Did you check your adb logcat for exceptions that are thrown?

After calling facebook.authorize, onComplete() is called, check:

```
public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
  String token = values.getString(Facebook.TOKEN);
  String expiresIn = values.getString(Facebook.EXPIRES);
}
```

Comment: I've edited the answer with an example to get the auth token expiration time.

Comment: Looking at my code and the onComplete function, I think my expiration is already unlimited.

Comment: It will be unlimited if you sent the "offline_acces" when asking for permissions. such as in:
fb.authorize(this, FacebookClientAppData.FACEBOOK_APP_ID, new String[] {..., "offline_access"}, this);

Comment: I've added it to the permissions but I am still getting the error.

Comment: Furthermore, the authorize function call you have there doesn't match any function I can call with those parameters.

Comment: Did you check your log for exceptions?

Comment: Yes, using the LogCat, I found - "DEBUG/Facebook-WebView(15156): Redirect URL: fbconnect://success/?error_code=110&error_msg=Missing+user+cookie+%28to+validate+session+user%29"